# Why does the Alloy analyzer fail to find a counter example to the following assertion?

Tags: alloy

Checking the following assertion produces no counter examples:

```
assert G4_3__10
{ 
  all x : Int | (x = 1) 
}
check G4_3__10
```

Produces the following output:

```
Executing "Check G4_3__10"

Solver=sat4j Bitwidth=0 MaxSeq=0 SkolemDepth=1 Symmetry=20
0 vars. 0 primary vars. 0 clauses. 4ms.
No counterexample found. Assertion may be valid. 0ms.
```

It does find a counter example when I add facts or signatures that 
use Ints (for example, adding

```
fact { 0 in Int }
```

Can anyone explain the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 3):

As you do not enforce the set of Integer to be non-empty in your original model, the analysis will only consider instances with no Integers. Your assertion will thus always hold hence no counter-example will be found.

The fact added in your second attempt pushes Alloy to consider instances where 0 is in the set of Integers. Alloy, will implicitly associate the default bitwith of 4 to Int, so that instances considered now contain integers in the interval [-8,7]. In those instances counter examples will befound.

You could also explicitly specify the Integer bitwidth to be used in your check command (rather than using this dummy fact) to enforce the presence of integers, e.g:     `check G4_3__10 for 4 Int`

Comment: Hm... but this behavior is different from what we get for 'plain' sigs. For example Alloy does not need to be 'pushed' to consider non empty sets for the following assertion:

    sig A {}

    check { 
      all a1, a2 : A | a1 = a2
    }

Comment: That's because Int is a built in sig, just like seq/Int and String. By default you won't have any atoms conforming to those signatures in your instances. 
IMHO, they took this design decision to minimize the size of the analysis domain.

Comment: Yes, I agree, especially as integers are very expensive to check. But I think it is a bit inelegant that these implementation details leak through to the user interface. Cheers :)